# Преобразование класса, имеющий в наследовании этот класс

Tags: kotlin

Пока делал программу, наткнулся на проблему. Минимальный код для репродукции:

```kotlin
class A : ArrayList<Int>(){}

fun main() {
    val listA = listOf(1, 3, 2)
    val B = listA as A
}
```

Этот код выкидывает исключение:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to class A`

Но почему? Ведь класс `A` является `ArrayList`, так в чем проблема? Просто не могу этого понять, спасибо заранее за пояснение

Comment: Кошка и собака млекопитающие. Но это не значит что любое млекопитающее есть кошка. Но любая кошка будет млекопитающее. Иными словами кастить можно только в одну сторону.

Comment: `Ведь класс A является ArrayList, так в чем проблема?` Ну так класс A является ArrayList, а не ArrayList является A, как в `listA as A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так будет работать

```
typealias A = ArrayList<Int>

fun main() {
    val listA = ArrayList<Int>()
    val B = listA as A
}
```

`listOf()` возвращает другой тип, он не будет каститься напрямую в стандартный `ArrayList`.